# How to return both Response.text() and Response from async function?

Tags: asynchronous, rust

I am trying to build an program that performs async http requests and returns their Response + body.

This is what the function that returns the Response looks like:

```rust
let responses = stream::iter(urls)
        .map(|line| {
            let client = &client;
            async move {
                client.get(&line).send().await.map(|resp| {   
                    (line, resp)
                })}
        })
        .buffer_unordered(concurrency_amount);
```

However, after returning `resp`, I can't use `resp.text()`, since `resp.text()` is of type `Future<Output=Result<String>>`.

How can I make the function also return `resp.text()` in the tuple?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context here? Presumably you're using `reqwest` and `Client` and `Response` correspond to that crate but it's hard to guess without getting more context.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough. Yes, I am using reqwest to send http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `reqwest`, it should be possible to collect the bytes of the response body with `Response::chunk()`, `text()` consumes `self` but `chunk()` only takes a mutable reference.

Something like the following collects the response body and decodes it to a String in a lossy manner.

```
use futures_util::StreamExt;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let cli = reqwest::Client::new();
    let urls = vec![
        "https://stackoverflow.com".to_string(),
        "https://google.com".into(),
        "https://tokio.rs".into(),
    ];
    let responses = futures_util::stream::iter(urls.into_iter())
        .then(|url| { // note that I replaced `map` with `then` here.
            let cli = cli.clone();
            async move {
                let mut resp = cli.get(url.clone()).send().await.unwrap();
                let mut body = Vec::new();
                while let Some(chunk) = resp.chunk().await.unwrap() {
                    body.extend_from_slice(&*chunk);
                }
                (url, resp, String::from_utf8_lossy(&body).to_string())
            }
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .await;
    for (url, response, text) in responses {
        println!("url: {} status: {} text: {}", url, response.status(), text);
    }
}
```

As the in-line comment notes: I changed the `map()` call to `then()` so the stream yields the tuples rather than futures with the tuples as output.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
let responses = stream::iter(urls)
        .map(|line| {
            let client = &client;
            (async move || {
                let resp = client.get(&line).send().await?;
                let text = resp.text().await?;
                (line, resp, text)
            })()
        })
        .buffer_unordered(concurrency_amount);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it returns `error[E0658]: async closures are unstable`
I also tried removing the `||` as the compiler suggests, however that returns further errors.

Comment: Also, I just noticed that `Response::text` accepts `self`, not `&self`, so this wouldn't work anyways...